# How auto enable permalinks for WordPress custom posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

When we register custom posts in WordPress, we have to Save permalinks to enable custom posts. Is there any method to avoid this hurdle? How can enable custom posts without going in Permalinks settings to Save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is flush_rewrite_rules(), which you would put into your code after you register the post type.

**HOWEVER**, you really only want to do this once, not every single time a page loads.  So if you're writing a plugin, you can use the [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) hook to run code when a plugin is activated.

If you are doing this in a theme, you'll have to do a bit of code to make sure this doesn't run each time.  You can save a value into the options table after this is run, so that it won't run again:

```
function save_rewrite_flush_status() {
    // look in the options table and see if you've flushed the rewrite rules
    if ( !get_option( 'rewrite_rules_flushed') ) {
        // if not, then flush them.
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        // set the option saying that you've flushed them, so this won't ever run again
        update_option( 'rewrite_rules_flushed', true );
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'save_rewrite_flush_status');
```